# Point halving on elliptic curves of even order

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am trying to understand how point halving on elliptic curves of even order works. Specifically: suppose $g$ is an elliptic curve, and $G$ is a generator point on this curve. The order of group generated by $G$ is even and equal to $q$. Suppose also that $A = x \cdot G$. I know $A$ but I don't know $x$.

My questions are:

1. What algorithm(s) could I use to calculate $A' = \frac{A}{2}$ such that $2 \cdot A' = A$?
2. When $x$ is odd, is the division undefined? Would the halving algorithm detect odd points?
3. When $x$ is even, my understanding is that there are two solutions $A' =\frac{x}{2} \cdot G =\frac{x + q}{2} \cdot G$. Is there an algorithm that would consistently differentiate between the first and second solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposed $Q = (q_x,q_y)$ is a point on elliptic curve $E$ defined by $y^{2} = x^{3} + ax^{2} + bx + c$. To  find the half point $P$ of  $Q$, we need to do the following:

1. **Write down the equation for the derivative of $E$ at $P$.** letting $\lambda$ be the derivative, we have
   **$\lambda = \dfrac{3x^{2} + 2ax +  b}   
       {2(x^{3}  + ax^{2} + bx + c)^{1/2}} \tag{1} \label{1}$**
2. **Write down the equation for  the tangent line to $E$ at $P$**:
   $y-p_y = \lambda(x-p_y) \quad\implies\quad y = \lambda(x - p_x) + p_y \tag{2}$.
3. **Write the equation for the intersection of the tangent line with E**:
   $y^{2} = (\lambda(x - p_x) + p_y)^{2} = x^{3} + ax^{2} + bx +
       c \tag{3}$.
4. **Write down $\lambda$ in terms of $p_x$**:
   The equation from (3) comes out
   to a monic cubic polynomial. Since it is monic,
   the sum of the roots add up to minus the coefficient of $x^{2}$. The
   roots are the intersection points. Hence $p_x$ will be a double root, and $q_x$ will be the third root. If you simplify this equation, you will see that the coefficient of the $x^{2}$ term is $a - \lambda^{2}$. Therefore $2p_x + q_x = \lambda^{2} - a $ and so $\lambda^{2} = 2p_x + q_x + a  \tag{4} \label{4}$
5. **Set equation from (4) and equation from (1) equal to  eachother**.
   Combining equation $\eqref{4}$ with the equation for $\eqref{1}$ and replacing $x$ with $p_x$, we get
   $\lambda^{2} = 2p_x + q_x + a
           =  \dfrac{(3p_x^{2} + 2ap_x +  b)^{2}}{4(p_x^{3}  + ap_x^{2} + bp_x + c)} \tag{5} \label{5}$.
   Simplifying this equation and moving everything over to
   the left hand side ***will yield a quartic polynomial in $p_x$. The roots of this polynomial are the x-coordinates of the half points of Q.***.

---

The relationship  between  the half points of $Q$ is the  same as  the relationship between  the roots of $\eqref{5}$. It will change depending on the nature of $E$. Here are a few things we can say for certain.

1. Since neither $q_y$ nor $p_y$ make an appearance in this quartic polynomial, each quartic polynomial will actually give the  halves for *two separate points*. The quartic from $\eqref{5}$ gives us the half points of $Q = (q_x,q_y)$ as  well as the half points of $-Q=(q_x,-q_y)$.
2. To find out if a half point exists for a point $Q$, there is a value you can calculate based on $a,b,c$ of $E$ and $q_x$. This procedure can be found on page 5 of **[Quartic Equations and 2-division on Elliptic Curves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.4379.pdf)** (Most of the results from this answer are directly from this paper).
3. If the points on E make up an odd ordered group, then each point $Q$
   only has one point $P$, and hence the quartic equation will only
   have one root. This follows from the fact that
   [elements in odd groups have unique square roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736008/element-of-odd-finite-group-has-unique-square-root).In this case, the factors of the quartic polynomial will be a linear equation and an irreducible resolvent cubic.
4. Equation (5) is equal to $(x-s)^{2}(x-t)^{2} \iff Q$ is a 2-torsion point. In this
   case, $Q$ will have two distinct halves, one where $x=s$ and another
   where $x=t$. $-Q$ will also have halves with these x-coordinates.
5. Equation (5) is equal to $(x-s)^{4} \iff Q$ is a singularity.

Comment: It may of interest to note that $\gcd(q,k)=1$ needs to hold if one wants to divide a point by $k$ in a (sub-)group of order $q$ (the order having to be even for halving follows from that).

Comment: A couple of clarifying questions: (1) do you mean section 3.6.1 in the book (I don't think section 3.8.1 exists there)? (2) for points that exist in odd subgroups of $G$ are there always two solutions? I'm assuming only one of them could be found using the algorithm, but the second solution still exists - right?

Comment: 1)Algorithm 3.8.1 in section 3.6.1. I’ll change the answer to reflect that. 2)Points that can be halved will always only have one solution.

Comment: Because points of even order don't always have a half - halving of even ordered points isn't used much in cryptography. That's probably why you had a hard time finding anything on  it. It is discussed more in general  group theory. Here are  two resources that discuss halving of even ordered points on elliptic curves - this one http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2005-74-249/S0025-5718-04-01640-0/S0025-5718-04-01640-0.pdf  ,  and  https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/66da/e203d7c0da46ca519fb5115ebe4e1f9c37fb.pdf .

Comment: But they both require a lot of background knowledge. I do intend to come back to this answer and give a more thorough response, but I need to do some reading first.

Comment: @irakliy - I updated  the answer  with more info.

Comment: The right hand side of the equation (5) has to be divided by 4 instead of 2 since the square of 1/2 in the equation (1) is 1/4 and not 1/2?

Comment: There is a little mistake in equation (5): denominator should have a constant factor 4 instead of 2, since the value 2 from equation (1) is squared.

Comment: @Icarus and toongeorges - thank you, just fixed it