# substract points on secp256k - result as moved to N-1

Tags: secp256k1

I must perform calculate of substract two points:

Let $G$ be the generator point and;

$P_1 =[1]G = (x_1,y_1)$

$P_2 = [2]G = (x_2,y_2)$,

When I will subtract $P_1 - P_2$ -> I will move Point to N-1 with negative $y_1$ of $P_1$

second:
Let $G$ be the generator point and;

$P_5 =[5]G = (x_1,y_1)$

$P_2 = [2]G = (x_2,y_2)$,

$P_3 = [3]G = (x_3,y_3)$,

When I will subtract $P_2 - P_5$ -> I will take result $P_3$ with  negative $y_3$ of $P_3$

it looks like $P_2 - P_5$  it "similiar" to integer 2 minus integer 5 = we get minus 3 - and in this example -3 it is N-3 .

How to check that substract points cross the order of curve n? without checking  y is negative?
how to check that substract point is crossed by Point of Infinity and order of the curve?

Ps. N = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141
order of curve -> maximum points.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. do you mean $P_1 = [1]G$ and $P_2=[2]G$? We have $\LaTeX$/MathJax enabled our site. Currently, you question is not clear. Note that, the point doesn't have floating points. $1/5$ probably means that $5^{-1}$ on the defined field.

Comment: P1=[1]G and P2=[2]G? Yes         but 1/5 = 0.2 of P it is halfing_point by 5 it is like 0.2 of P. and we have P_1.2[G] it is equals P + halfing P by 5  . and how to check that substract is moved N-1 curve order?

Comment: "0.2 of P it is halfing_point by 5"; I am not familiar with that terminology (and I suspect others may be in the same boat); what operation are you performing on $P$?  Is it 'find the point $Q$ with $5Q = P$, and return $Q$?'

Comment: @poncho [point halving possible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66106/18298), however, the Q is not clear to me.

Comment: @kelalaka: I know there is a well defined operation "point halving", however I'm not certain what he means by "point halving by 5"

Comment: fthe calculate looks like :

Comment: the calculate looks like :    divide_mode_n_by_2 =  1 / GF(n)(2)  * P[1]G = 1/2P , and divide_mode_n_by_5 =  1 / GF(n)(5) * P[1] = P[0.2] = 1/5 P . And P1_2 = P + 0.2P. is now clear?

Comment: I've edited some, and you can do the rest, as far as I can see.

Comment: edited to better understand. Thanks Kelalaka

Answer (score 1):

> How to check that substract points cross the order of curve n?

You cant'; or at least, we hope you can't.

If you could, you could use that method to compute discrete logs.

Here is one approach; suppose you had a method that, given the points $[a]G$ and $[b]G$, would return you $[a-b]G$ and also informed you whether it "crossed the order of curve n", that is, if $a < b$.  Then, what you could do, given the point $[x]G$, you could use this method on the points $[x]G$ and $[\lfloor n/2 \rfloor]G$; that method would tell you if $x < \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.  If it turned out (for example) if $x$ happened to be larger, you could repeat this with $[x]G$ and $[\lfloor 3n/5 \rfloor]G$; and continue to do binary searching until you have recovered the value of $x$.

That means that you've just recovered the discrete log of $xG$ with only circa $\log_2(n)$ calls to your method; we certainly hope that we can't do that.

BTW: why do you care if "the points cross the order of curve n"?

Comment: If I know that point of substracted -> crossed the order , then I can make "application" for curve.   If its not possible, maybe "how to check" that substract point moved by Point Infinity is possibility?

Comment: @Ironic: 'then I can make "application" for curve' - I have no idea what that means

Comment: imagine calculator like in Windows system. you can add, substract, multiply, and divide. but designed for curves.

Comment: @Ironic: if your EC calculator has things entered as $(x, y)$ coordinates, you can compute point subtraction using the standard algorithm without knowing/caring whether the result "crossed the order" (which, btw, makes sense only in terms of a specific generator).  And, if it has things entered as discrete logs (e.g. 3 for [3]G), then its even easier...